# How do you connect an IBM Cloud Functions (OpenWhisk) to a custom domain?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I had successfully setup a custom domain with IBM Cloud Functions in the past, but now suddenly it seems to be broken.

Here is how I was able to do it in the past: You first need to install a SSL cert in IBM Cloud by going to:

1. Log in to IBM Cloud
2. Go to **Manage>Accounts>Cloud Foundry Orgs**.
3. Click on your Org and then click **Edit Org**.
4. Choose the **Domain** tab, add a domain, and install the SSL cert that was purchased or obtained for free by letsencrypt.org
5. Go to Cloud Functions page by clicking on the Hamburger menu
   and then click **Functions**.
6. Click **APIs** on the sidebar.
7. Choose an existing API you would like to map to the domain.
8. Choose **Definitions** from the sidebar.
9. Select **Domain for API** and change it your new domain!

YAY, IBM Cloud says it is now connecting your custom domain. You get a warning about how it takes a bit of time, **but the task never finishes**.

This actually worked until about a month or so ago. Now it just sits there and it will not route your domain to your API.

If you hit the site you which is routed, it will say:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('yourdomain.com') does not exist.
```

Am I missing something? Or has IBM again crapped out on me.

Comment: There's a known issue affecting this feature currently, but it is being worked on. We'll update you when it's fixed. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Quackquack I'm curious, you write "Or has IBM again crapped out on me". Have you had other breaking issues with the Cloud Functions? Because my team is considering to build a large project on top of it, but if it's got issues - we might need to reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug affecting this feature, but it has since been fixed. Give it another try.

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm not seeing the "Domain for API" option at all inside the "Definition" page of a Cloud Functions API I've set up. Is it known this bug is still present? (I'm in the UK region if that makes a difference).

Comment: Custom domains are currently available only in the US South region. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ah okay, that explains that then. Are there any plans on the roadmap to make them available in the UK region too?

Comment: I was just about to use custom domains as well, It's a requirement if I'm at all going to use IBM Cloud functions - but it's only available on the US South, still.

Comment: The feature will be made available globally within 3Q2018.